# Sign In with Google Authentication

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-authentication

I've implemented Google Authentication via Firebase in my App. Everything works smoothly except for one small problem that I can't seem to find. Whenever the user opens the page that prompts them to "Sign in with Google" (ie. login page or sign up page), the banner appears momentarily before disappearing. I do not want it to appear at all, unless the user clicks the "Sign in with Google" button. How can I get rid of this?

WelcomeViewController (the view controller with the google login)

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase
import FBSDKLoginKit
import GoogleSignIn
 
class WelcomeViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var signInFacebookButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var signInGoogleButton: UIButton!
     
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setUpGoogleButton()
            
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
    }
    
// SIGN IN WITH GOOGLE
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if let err = error {
            print("Failed to log into Google: ", err)
            return
        }
        print("Successfully logged into Google")
        
        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
        
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
            if let err = error {
                print("Failed to create a Firebase User with Google account: ", err)
                return
            }
            // Successfully logged in
            guard let uid = user?.user.uid else { return }
            print("Successfully logged into Firebase with Google", uid)
            // switch to tab bar controller
            let tabBarC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainTabBarController") as! TabBarController
            tabBarC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            self.present(tabBarC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            print("Switched to TabBarController")
        })
    }
    
    fileprivate func setUpGoogleButton() {
        let button = signInGoogleButton
        button?.layer.borderWidth = 0
        button?.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 130/255, green: 178/255, blue: 189/255, alpha: 1)
        button?.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
        button?.tintColor = UIColor.white
        button!.addTarget(self, action:
                            #selector(handleCustomGoogleSignIn), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.delegate = self
        }
    
    @objc func handleCustomGoogleSignIn() {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
        }
```

I've attached a link to a screen recording of what happens. The second page shown in the screen recording is identical to the code below, so it has the same problem. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t4KV0Z6qwfCK56Gf2314wXWhAeQR0wUs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your code is causing the problem. You are redirecting the user to a Google endpoint for authorization. Google determines that the user is still authenticated and returns to your site. Your authorization code does not keep track that the user is already logged in (authenticated). I will leave the debugging to you as I do not write code for your platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of your code inside *viewDidLoad()*. You are implementing this method:

```swift
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
```

This triggers the sign in method as soon as the view loads (as you are implementing it inside *viewDidLoad()*), and that causes that momentary sign in pop up that disappears.

Instead of implementing that method there, you should only implement it inside your *handleCustomGoogleSignIn()*.

Conclusion, your viewDidLoad() should look like this:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setUpGoogleButton()
            
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
    }
```